# make: Package python was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: python, makefile, pip

```
$ make
pip install runcython
Requirement already satisfied: runcython in d:\programfiles\conda\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.10 in d:\programfiles\conda\lib\site-packages (from runcython)
makecython++ stitch_wrapper.pyx "" "stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"
Package python was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `python.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'python' found
stitch_wrapper.cpp:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all-python2] Error 1
```

Trying to compile some utils written in c++, but get this error:

> Package python was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Utils folder includes .cpp and .py files (uses also Python for something)

I have python 3.6.1

> make: *** [all-python2] Error 1

Seems it wants python 2.

But I'm not sure if after installing python 2.* and adding it to system variables issue will disappear . Who know for sure?

**update**

though makefiles has python 3 lines:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: all-python2 all-python3
all-python2:
    pip install runcython
    makecython++ stitch_wrapper.pyx "" "stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"

all-python3:
    pip3 install runcython3
    makecython3++ stitch_wrapper.pyx "" "stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"
```

Comment: by default, `make` will try to complete the first target, that is `all-python2` in your situation. Can you try the Python 3 version with `make all-python3`?

Comment: Also, there is a note on the page of [runcython](https://github.com/Russell91/runcython#configuration-for-anaconda) that your makefile relies on about needing the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl same error

Comment: You mean, after having read and applied (if so, please specify fully how) the instructions in the link?

Answer (score 4):

For me on Arch Linux (4.15.11-1), makecython was unable to find `python.pc` too.
I checked `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` and found out that the respective searchpath only contained the files `python3.pc` and `python2.pc`.

So I added a symlink using `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc /usr/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc` and now everything is working fine.